# Inverse SQL script auto-generation

Tags: database, oracle

Is there a way to auto-generate an SQL script that rollback modifications of an other script in Oracle Database ?

Example :

"Script1" : 
Insert into tableX

"Script"2 (auto-generated) : delete from tableX

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I believe this kind of question is too broad for SO.

Comment: Such a tool cannot exist as the effect of the primary script also depends on the database contents. So you cannot generate the inverse script without knowing the database contents at the moment the primary script is executed.

Comment: You can explore the flashback feature and based on that you can create scripts